# How to create multiple sprites(nodes) with the same texture that will automatically generate a new when one node is removed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm trying to create a game where the user can swipe a node and once it's swiped a new node will be created at the bottom of the screen and push all other nodes up, kind of like a reverse Tetris.  Here is a very basic image to give you an idea:[image: nodes]

I've be able to figure out how to swipe the node off screen but can't seem to figure out how to have all the other nodes move up a row and have a new node created at the bottom.  I tried doing an "addChild" for the node I just swiped so it can appear again at the bottom but keep getting an error stating the node already has a parent.  Here is my code so far:

```
import SpriteKit


let plankName = "woodPlank"

class PlankScene: SKScene {

  var plankWood : SKSpriteNode?


  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    plankWood = childNode(withName: "woodPlank") as? SKSpriteNode


    let swipeRight : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PlankScene.swipedRight))

    swipeRight.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

  }


  func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.direction == .right {

    let moveOffScreenRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: 400, duration: 0.5)

    let nodeFinishedMoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()

      plankWood?.run(SKAction.sequence([moveOffScreenRight, nodeFinishedMoving]))

      plankWood?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -250)
      addChild(plankWood!)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't move it x:400 but lets say x:20, do you see it disappearing or is it still on screen? If it's staying on the screen, it's not removing itself from the parent correctly.

Comment: `.copy()` lets you duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As @KnightOfDragon said you can create a copy of your `plankWood` sprite using `.copy()` so you could create a function to add a plank kind of like this one:

```
func addPlank() {
    let newPlank = plankWood.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    newPlank.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -250) //This should be your first plank position

    addChild(newPlank)
}
```

And then you should have an array of `SKSpriteNode` holding your planks and you could have a function like this to move your other planks up:

```
func movePlanksUp() {
    for node:SKSpriteNode in yourPlankArray {
        node.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250), duration: 0.10))
    }
}
```

Also if you are creating a `plankArray` you should add this line of code to your `addPlank()`function: `yourPlankArray.append(newPlank)`

I hope this helps feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: This kind of works but the outcome is a bit wonky. Whenever I slide the plank to be removed the addPlank function causes a new plank to appear and the movePlansUp function causes the new plan that was just added to attach to the current plank that is being swiped off screen making one giant plank.

Comment: This is what the function looks like:  func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if sender.direction == .right {
    
    let moveOffScreenRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: 400, duration: 0.5)
    
    let nodeFinishedMoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()
      
      plankWood?.run(SKAction.sequence([moveOffScreenRight, nodeFinishedMoving]))

    

      self.addPlank()
      self.movePlanksUp()

    }

  }