# How to replace a sprite node with a new node once it's swiped off screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I currently have a scene with a bunch of nodes set up in rows. Each row has one node that can be swiped off screen. Once the node is swiped off screen the node in the row beneath it will move up to take the place of the node that was swiped off screen.  I know how to swipe off the nodes off screen but am having problems with moving the all the rows up to take fill the empty row.  Right now when I swipe only one of the rows moves offscreen but all the other nodes stay on screen and won't swipe off.  I can see the new nodes are being generated but the other nodes currently on the screen are unaffected by the new node and instead the new node overlaps the other nodes on the screen. I currently have the nodes created in the .sks file here: [image: sks]

I had some help earlier from this post: [How to create multiple sprites(nodes) with the same texture that will automatically generate a new when one node is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800600/how-to-create-multiple-spritesnodes-with-the-same-texture-that-will-automatica/39842169#39842169)

Here is my code:

```
let plankName = "woodPlank"

class PlankScene: SKScene {

  var plankWood : SKSpriteNode?

  var plankArray : [SKSpriteNode] = []





  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: plankName) {
      node, stop in
      self.plankWood = node as? SKSpriteNode

      let swipeRight : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PlankScene.swipedRight))

      swipeRight.direction = .right

      view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    }

  }



  func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.direction == .right {

      swipeAndAddPlank(completion: {
        self.addPlank(completion: {
        self.movePlanksUp()
        })

      })
    }
  }


  func swipeAndAddPlank(completion: (()->Void)?) {

    let moveOffScreenRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: 400, duration: 0.5)

    let nodeFinishedMoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    //let completionAction = SKAction.run({completion!()})

    plankWood?.run(SKAction.sequence([moveOffScreenRight,nodeFinishedMoving]))

    completion?()

  }


    func addPlank(completion: (()->Void)?) {
    let newPlank = plankWood?.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    newPlank.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -259)
    plankArray.append(newPlank)
    print(plankArray.count)
    addChild(newPlank)

    completion?()

  }


  func movePlanksUp() {
    for node:SKSpriteNode in plankArray {
      node.run(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50), duration: 0.10))
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: if you add Physics category affected by gravity, maybe you can achieve the goal

Comment: hmm Physics may be overkill,  if not done right, the columns may not stack straight, or cause unwanted bouncy effects.  If I were you, when going through your array, when you hit a spot where you no longer have a node, you have a boolean you set to true,  then any plank after that you move move up because this boolean is activated